# Do a rescue_from on Twitter::Error and still load view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, twitter-gem

I want to catch a Twitter::Error that happens in a view partial and still load the page. Put another way, I don't want a Twitter::Error to stop the page from loading. I just want that partial to not be loaded.

https://gist.github.com/scottmagdalein/903cd168ea4171365d51

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rescue from errors to allow what you need:

```
def my_method
  begin
    # do some things
  rescue Twitter::Error
    flash[:notice] = 'oh dear!'
  end

  # any other view code
end
```

You catch the error, set a message, then continue to your view.

Comment: It doesn't really matter what goes there, could be nothing at all, just making the point that the code will continue after the rescue, not halt.